# How to run only tests that contain both groupA and groupB (both. not either or)

Tags: testng

Is it possible in TestNG to run tests that contain 2 groups (groupA & groupB) but not tests that only contain one or the other

e.g:

- method1 has groupA & groupB
- method2 has groupB
- method3 has groupA

Goal:
I want to run tests that contain both groupA & groupB but not tests that only contain one or the other. In this case, I would only want method1 to be executed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with "plain" xml config which operates with includes and excludes.

Take a look at a tasty  feature of using [BeanShell scripts](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell) inside `<method-selector>` tag.

Some usage example is available at http://blog.strug.de/tag/testng/

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm :) The following worked fine: `<method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[groups.containsKey("groupA")&&groups.containsKey("groupB")]]></script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>`